# HTTP Content-Encoding gzip detect end of stream

Tags: sockets, http, gzip

I'm developing a custom HTTP library for my use. At the moment I'm implementing various transfer types and I'm stuck on how to read all data from the socket when `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`. I have checked the `GZIP` file format and there is no specified indication that end of `gzip` file has been reached.

Chunked transfer indicates where last chunk ends with `0\r\n\r\n`. 
Is there a way to check if end of a `gzip` stream has been reached?

Answer (score 2):

There is no end of stream indicator in gzip. You have to use the indicator of the encapsulating layer (i.e. HTTP) to find out where the gzip stream ends, i.e. depending on the response header either the content-length, the last chunk in chunked encoding or the end of the TCP connection.

Comment: I have a solution for chunked encoding, however when only Content-Length and Content-Encoding are present I dont understand how I could detect end of data. Sometimes checking if there is data to be read can return invalid results.

Also, does Content-Length provide length of Content-Type (ie after being decompressed) or is it the length of content during transfer?

Comment: If the response is not `chunked`, you have to rely on `Content-Length` or socket closure to detect end-of-data. If `Content-Length` is present, it is the exact byte length of the data being transmitted, so stop reading when you have read that many bytes. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for more details.

Comment: HTTP has no real concept of compression (that is handled by the sender and receiver outside of HTTP) and so it does not report the size of the uncompressed data.